# inner return not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, render

Depending on what the results of the graphql query are, I am rendering some items in the function `contact`

```
export const Whitelist: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersQueryHookResult>('');

  const called = () => {
    console.log('inner return')
  }
  const contacts = () => {
    console.log('running');
    const { loading, error, data } = useUsersQuery({
      variables: {
        where: { id: 34 },
      },
    });
    console.log('DATA COMING', data);
    return (
      <View style={styles.allUsers}>
        {data.users.nodes.map(
          (item: { firstName: string; lastName: string; id: number }) => {
            const userName = item.firstName
              .concat(' ')
              .concat(item.lastName);
            return (           
              <View style={styles.item} key={item.id}>
                  {called()}  
                <Thumbnail
                  style={styles.thumbnail}
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatars-xmas-giveaway/128/afro_woman_female_person-512.png',
                  }}></Thumbnail>
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
                <View style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                  <Button
                    rounded
                    style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Icon
                      name="plus"
                      size={moderateScale(20)}
                      color="black"
                    />
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Container style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Item style={styles.addToWhitelist}>
          <Icon
            name="add"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddContactTry')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.addToContactTitle}>Add contact</Text>
        </Item>
        <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>Zurück</Text>
        {contacts()}
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

However, I don't see any items rendered. If I render something after the first return in `contacts`(for example a thumbnail), I am able to see that. However, I don't see anything from the second return. How can I fix this?

I tried to use `{called()}` in the inner return to debug. It should show a log but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the request to finish. Your request is sent and immediately after that your return is executed and doesn't have what to render since data is empty. Declare your function as async and await for the request to finish

Comment: But I read that the query hook doesn't return a promise so I cannot use try catch blocks here. Could you please give an example on how I can achieve what you said?